# Special language characters in username of ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I would like to use some special characters like `ø` in user name.

But I am facing this error in

```
IdentityResult result = UserManager.Create(applicationUser, password);
```

**Error:**

> User name testø is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.

How we can fix it?
How to allow some special characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found what do I have to do

```
 public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager()
            : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
        {
            PasswordValidator = new MinimumLengthValidator(4);
            UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
            { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false  }; 
        }
    }
```