# ASP.NET Identity AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Can someone please help me how can i use special characters in ASP.Net identity?
The problem is that my users cannot register with special characters: č,ć,š,ž,đ. 
When you try to enter this characters in registration, i get following error:
User name Krešo is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.

Where and how can i change this.

Here is the code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Pages_Account_Register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnPrijava_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserStore<IdentityUser> userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();

        userStore.Context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString =
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SeminariConnectionString3"].ConnectionString;

        UserManager<IdentityUser> manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

        IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser();

        user.UserName = txtKorisnickoIme.Text;

        if(txtLozinka.Text == txtPotvrdaLozinke.Text)
        {

            try
            {
                IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, txtLozinka.Text);

                if(result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
                    var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties(), userIdentity);

                    Response.Redirect("Pocetna.aspx");

                }

                else
                {
                    litStatus.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                litStatus.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
        }

        else
        {

            litStatus.Text = "Lozinke moraju biti identične.";
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special language characters in username of ASP.NET Identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909286/special-language-characters-in-username-of-asp-net-identity)

Comment: I already saw this answer, but i don't know how to use this class in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change this behaviour as follows:

```
var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);  // existing code
var validator = manager.UserValidator as UserValidator<ApplicationUser>;
if (validator != null) validator.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false;
```

Should `validator` turn out to be null, then debug a little to find the actual type used at runtime.

Comment: I am missing ApplicationUser. Where should i create it? I don't have identityconfig class.

Comment: In my case it was automatically generated from the VS2015 MVC project template. It inherits from `IdentityUser` which is present in your code (perhaps resulting from an older MVC template). Please try using **`IdentityUser`** instead of `ApplicationUser`.

Comment: i used IdentityUser and validator is null

Comment: var validator = manager.UserValidator as UserValidator<IdentityUser>;

        if (validator != null) validator.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false;

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line, inspect or watch `manager.UserValidator`, VS should then show the type.

Comment: I debugged it. I watched manager.UserValidator, but where could i find the type.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/15/7-ways-to-look-at-the-values-of-variables-while-debugging-in-visual-studio/

Comment: i used quickwatch to inspect it, but i dont know what to check